# Clone a LinkedList with each node having a next and a random pointer

Tags: java, linked-list

The `LinkedList` nodes can be 1-->2-->3-->4, where --> indicates next. For their random pointers: 1--> 2, 2--> 4 3-->2 4--1. There can be duplicate data values of the nodes. I'm looking to see if the solution can be improved upon.

```
class Node
{
int data;//Node data
Node next, random;//Next and random reference

//Node constructor
public Node(int data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.next = this.random = null;
}
}

// linked list class
class LinkedList
{
Node head;//Linked list head reference

// Linked list constructor
public LinkedList(Node head)
{
    this.head = head;
}

// push method to put data always at the head
// in the linked list.
public void push(int data)
{
    Node node = new Node(data);
    node.next = this.head;
    this.head = node;
}

// Method to print the list.
void print()
{
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null)
    {
        Node random = temp.random;
        int randomData = (random != null)? random.data: -1;
        System.out.println("Data = " + temp.data +
                ", Random data = "+ randomData);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    }

// Actual clone method which returns head
// reference of cloned linked list.
public LinkedList clone()
{
    // Initialize two references, one with original
    // list's head.
    Node origCurr = this.head, cloneCurr = null;

    // Hash map which contains node to node mapping of
    // original and clone linked list.
    Map<Node, Node> map = new HashMap<Node, Node>();

    // Traverse the original list to help copy into the HashMap
    while (origCurr != null) {
        cloneCurr = new Node(origCurr.data);
        cloneCurr.next = origCurr.next;
        cloneCurr.random = origCurr.random;
        map.put(origCurr, cloneCurr);
        origCurr = origCurr.next;
    }

    //return the head reference of the clone list.
    return new LinkedList(map.get(this.head));
}
}

public class Clone
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Pushing data in the linked list.
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList(new Node(5));
    list.push(4);
    list.push(3);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(1);


    list.head.random = list.head.next.next;
    list.head.next.random =
            list.head.next.next.next;
    list.head.next.next.random =
            list.head.next.next.next.next;
    list.head.next.next.next.random =
            list.head.next.next.next.next.next;
    list.head.next.next.next.next.random =
            list.head.next;

    // Making a clone of the original linked list.
    LinkedList clone = list.clone();

    // Print the original and cloned linked list.
    System.out.println("Original linked list");
    list.print();
    System.out.println("\nCloned linked list");
    clone.print();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Not a clone

Your "clone" is not a clone of the original list.  It is a single head node that points to the second node of the original list.  In order to make a real clone, all pointers in the cloned list should point only to other nodes in the cloned list.

#### Two passes

Your attempt isn't completely wrong.  After creating all the cloned nodes, you just need a second pass where you convert the original node pointers to cloned node pointers using the map you created.